# SAML Response not found

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, okta, onelogin

I've successfully implemented SAML in my application on my local machine (127.0.0.1). I initially used PHP-SAML from OneLogin as my intro to SAML, but tweaked my code to work with Okta as the IDP and my app as the SP. Everything works fine in my local tests. However, when moving the code to my VM, I get the following error:

> SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding

I used the SAML Tracer extension in Firefox, and SAML Message Decoder in Chrome, which shows that I'm getting a response, but the GET and POST superglobals are both empty. The HTTP headers from SAML Tracer shows there's a redirect, hence the:

> 302 Found

Here are screenshots of the SAML response from Tracer:

[image: Tracer 1]

I'm not sure where to go from here. The POST global on my VM is completely empty and the GET global has an `acs` parameter with an empty string as its value; yet the POST global on my local machine has the `SAMLResponse` and `RelayState` and an empty string as its `$_GET['acs']`.

Answer (score 0):

302 not found is a redirection. After that your variables will be empty so it is consistent with what you are seeing. You need to check what could be redirecting your request once it hits your VM. If it works in your local you are on the right track.